# How can i derive the potential energy density of a sound wave or any longitudinal wave?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, potential-energy

I have been trying to derive the energy density( potential energy per unit length) relation for a sound wave. I tried to find the work done in compressing a volume element as negative of that must be the potential energy but I am unable to do it.

Comment: I don't think a sound wave in air $has$ any potential energy. If you squash or compress air by a small amount (as when a sound wave is passing through), it does behave rather like a spring, but the energy stored is actually kinetic rather than potential.

Comment: That is not correct, all the books I have read they clearly say that there is both potential and kinetic energy density and after all when a volume of air is compressed ( or a spring) work is done and thus work is stored as potential energy in it

Comment: Which books? I wonder. I'd go as far as saying that in the macroscopic view the oscillating 'layers' of air have kinetic energy and quasi-potential energy. On the level of molecules, though, I can't see how to justify potential energy.

Comment: books including French, Fox Smith's, David Morin's drafts all of them say that it has both potential and kinetic energy density

Comment: Yes, and two of my books (Braddick and Pain) talk about work and potential energy in just the same way that your writers do. I'm happy to do the same, but writing 'potential energy' in quotes for the reason I gave in my last comment.

Comment: Oh I see your point now....

Comment: Good. I've added another paragraph to my answer to explain what is going on. A mathematical treatment might follow.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simple harmonic plane wave (one whose wavefronts are plane), of frequency $f$ and amplitude $A$.

A particle of mass $m$ in the medium is therefore performing SHM and has total energy given by$$E_m=\tfrac12 m A^2 (2 \pi f)^2=2 \pi^2 m A^2 f^2.$$

If there are $\nu$ such particles per unit volume (and no particles with different masses from $m$) the energy per unit volume is 
$$\frac EV=2 \pi^2 \nu m A^2 f^2.$$
But density of medium is $\rho=\nu m,$ so
$$\frac EV=2 \pi^2 \rho A^2 f^2.$$
As with all simple harmonic oscillations half of this energy is kinetic and half of it is 'potential'. I put 'potential' in quotes, because in a gas (treated as ideal), on a microscopic level, there is no potential energy.

The changes in so-called 'potential energy' as a sound wave passes through a gas are in fact changes in *random kinetic energy* of the molecules. The rarefactions and compressions that take place in a 'slice' of air as a sound wave passes through are adiabatic, and the work done on the slice as it is compressed raises its internal energy, that is the random kinetic energy of the molecules. The reverse happens as the slice undergoes rarefaction.

You might think that the increase in random energy stored in the slice during compression is equal to the decrease during rarefaction, so that over a complete cycle the mean energy so stored is zero. This is not the case. A simple mathematical treatment shows that the increase and decrease are not quite equal and that the net effect is an increase in energy both on compression and on rarefaction. This is what some textbooks, rather misleadingly, call 'potential energy'.